# jest manual mock imports are not working

Tags: jestjs

For some reason Jest is not picking up my manual mock implementation. The structure is the following. Am I missing something here? It is for sure hoisting the .mock call, I've tested it with the mock call above imports and still no dice.

Appreciate any help.

--

```
// "@/store/modules/__tests__/data"
import {fetchData} from "@/store/modules/data"
import {fetchByids} from "@/api/fetch";
jest.mock("@/api/fetch");
...
[ fetchByIds is considered the original still ? ]
```

--

```
// "@/store/modules/data"
import {fetchByIds} from "@/api/fetch";
...
export const fetchData = (context, payload) => {
    fetchByIds(payload.id);
}
```

--

```
// "@/api/fetch"
export const fetchByIds = (id) => fetch(`url${id}`).then(response=>response.json())
```

--

```
// "@/api/__mocks__/fetch"
export const fetchByIds = jest.fn().mockImplementation(id => Promise.resolve({id}))
```

--

What's interesting is if I add the following to `"@/store/modules/__tests__/data"` it picks up the mock implementation. So maybe it's an issue with name mapping?

```
jest.mock("@/api/fetch", () => ({
    fetchByIds: jest.fn().mockImplementation(id => Promise.resolve({id}))
}));
```

Comment: I found some info here that may help answer this, I'm still trying to find a solution. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1290#issuecomment-267049429

Comment: well I found a hacky way, if I do `jest.mock("@/api/fetch", ()=>require("@/api/__mocks__/fetch"));` it works...